# Combine all animation state into one clip (.anim) file in unity

Tags: unity, c#, animation, animation-controller

I have an animation controller where different animation states(clips) are available. Like this:
[image]

**Now my aim is to convert all this states animation into a single clip (.anim file).** Is this possible. ?
I am able to copy one animation clips frame using [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/9121/how-does-one-copy-and-paste-keyframes-in-the-anima.html). But it very time consuming.